# PHP Composer Symfony error

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to download symfony using composer as per the instructions on symfony website.

I keep getting this error:

```
chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)
```

I have googled and there are no references to this.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Could describe each steap you've followed to get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you following these steps:

1/ `cd /htdocs` cd into the web directory (the folder where you want to install your symfony project)

2/ `curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php` to download composer files.

3/ `php composer.phar self-update` to obtain the last version of Composer.

4/ `php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition ./Symfony` to install the files in a folder called symfony (You can change the last argument to whatever path you prefer to have the project in).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is some kind of composer bug as it seems to be happening to other people. There is a recently open issue in github which you may like to follow.

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1041

In the meantime, you may try to download an earlier version of composer.phar and see if it works:

http://getcomposer.org/download/